# Spark Application Level logs in EMR step

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm running spark application in EMR step but job failed due to some error, I want to see that error. I have checked stderr but it is not giving any detailed information about error. It's saying that

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1593934145491_0002 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1149)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnClusterApplication.start(Client.scala:1526)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:853)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:928)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:937)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
20/07/05 07:50:37 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

Can anyone help me this ? I want to see application level logs.

Comment: Configure cluster logging to S3 as explained here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-debugging.html

Comment: You will be able to see all the logs on S3 under /container/application_id

Comment: Another good way just for troubleshooting is to set the --deploy-mode to be client instead of cluster but just for testing

Comment: on S3, it was making only two folders, one was step and other was node.

Comment: Okay after setting deploy mode to client, where can I find Spark Application Logs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After enabling Debugging mode and Running script on Client, I was able to see Spark Application level logs in Steps/Step_ID/stdout.gz

Answer (score 1):

It should be always under /container but if you cannot find it try to ssh the master node and run the spark-submit